# Conform to protocol on DEBUG configuration only

Tags: ios, debugging, swift, protocols

I'm trying to enable class protocol when `DEBUG` flag is set:

```
#if DEBUG
 class LoginViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
#else
 class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
#endif
     //...
 }
```

It does not compile though, "`Expected declaration`" on `#else` line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Preprocessor directives in swift are not the same as you might be used to using.

The [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_20) on the subject notes that anything contained between `#if`/`#else`/`#endif` statements must be valid swift statements on their own.

> In contrast with condition compilation statements in the C preprocessor, conditional compilation statements in Swift must completely surround blocks of code that are self-contained and syntactically valid. This is because all Swift code is syntax checked, even when it is not compiled.

Because your statements are fragments (ending in an open brace), they do not compile.

You may have to do something like the following to accomplish what you want:

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
  ...
}

#if DEBUG
class DebugLoginViewController: LoginViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
  (just add the UITextFieldDelegate code here
   let LoginViewController handle the rest)
}
#endif
```

Then you'll use a `#if DEBUG`/`#else`/`#endif` where you're instantiating your view controller to choose the `DebugLoginViewController` or not.

Comment: Or just define an `extension LoginViewController : UITextFieldDelegate { ... }` in the DEBUG case.

Comment: Also a good option. Really, the important thing to know is that you can't have partial statements within `#if`/`#else`/`#endif` in swift.

Answer (score 2):

Ian MacDonald has already explained the reason for the compiler error
perfectly, and proposed a good solution.

Just for the sake of completeness, here are two more possible solutions:

- Declare the text field delegate methods in an extension which is only
  defined in the DEBUG case:

  ```
  #if DEBUG
  extension LoginViewController : UITextFieldDelegate {
      // ...
  }
  #endif
  ```
- Define a custom protocol which is either aliased to `UITextFieldDelegate` or defined as an empty protocol:

  ```
  #if DEBUG
  typealias MyTextFieldDelegate = UITextFieldDelegate
  #else
  protocol MyTextFieldDelegate { }
  #endif

  class LoginViewController: UIViewController, MyTextFieldDelegate {
      // ...
  }
  ```

Comment: That second one is pretty clever, but I think the `extension` is generally better practice. :)